OpenTelemetry .NET SDK does not emit Traces
Please see the below code. I am trying to send Metrics and Traces from a minimal WebAPI to the Console and to the OTel collector (which forwards the traces to Grafana Tempo).
Metrics are sent to Prometheus correctly, and they appear on Console, too.
However, Traces do not appear on Console and they are not received by Opentelemetry collector (logs don't show anything) and Grafana Tempo is also empty.
I have even added an ActivityListener to write the activity name on Console when they start but nothing is seen on Console.
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Diagnostics.Metrics;
using OpenTelemetry.Exporter;
using OpenTelemetry.Metrics;
using OpenTelemetry.Resources;
using OpenTelemetry.Trace;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
var metricCollectorUrl = builder.Configuration["OtelMetricCollector:Host"] ?? "";
var traceCollectorUrl = builder.Configuration["OtelTraceCollector:Host"] ?? "";

builder.Services
    .AddMetrics()
    .AddOpenTelemetry()
    .ConfigureResource(r =>
    {
        r.AddService("OrderService");
    })
    .WithMetrics(m =>
    {
        m.AddMeter("OrderServiceMeter")
            .AddOtlpExporter(o =>
            {
                o.Protocol = OtlpExportProtocol.HttpProtobuf;
                o.Endpoint = new Uri(metricCollectorUrl);
            })
            .AddConsoleExporter();

    })
    .WithTracing(t =>
    {
        t.AddSource("Order Service APIs")
            .AddConsoleExporter()
            .AddOtlpExporter(o =>
            {
                o.Protocol = OtlpExportProtocol.HttpProtobuf;
                o.Endpoint = new Uri(traceCollectorUrl);
            });
    });


var app = builder.Build();

Counter<int>? otlOrderCount = null;

ActivitySource.AddActivityListener(new ActivityListener()
{
    ActivityStarted = r =>
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Activity {r.DisplayName} started.");
    }
});
app.MapGet("/", async (context) =>
{
    using var activity = Activity.Current?.Start();
    activity.SetTag("Service", "Order");
    activity.DisplayName = "Order Processing";

    var metricFactory = context.RequestServices.GetService<IMeterFactory>();
    var meter = metricFactory?.Create(new MeterOptions("OrderServiceMeter"));
    otlOrderCount = meter?.CreateCounter<int>("otel_order");

    otlOrderCount?.Add(1);

    using (var step1Activity = activity.Start()) // Create child spans within the root activity
    {
        step1Activity.SetTag("Step", "Get Customer Info.");
        step1Activity.DisplayName = "Customer Info";
        step1Activity.SetStatus(ActivityStatusCode.Ok);
            
    }

    using (var step2Activity = activity.Start())
    {
        step2Activity.SetTag("Step", "Get Shipping Info.");
        step2Activity.DisplayName = "Shipping Info";
        step2Activity.SetStatus(ActivityStatusCode.Ok);
    }

    activity.SetStatus(ActivityStatusCode.Ok); // Set status on root activity
});
app.Run();

Can you please guide me as where I am making a mistake?

There's a lot of things that are wrong with that, I'd suggest looking at the OpenTelemetry docs and following those before you try to amend the code.

Thanks.
Unfortunately the documentation of .Net SDK is a bit outdated and only has samples for MVC. I will do another round of reading.

The main example here is minimal apis. https://opentelemetry.io/docs/languages/net/getting-started/
